# SQL Server XML with where clause and select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
ID  Status  LOAD
1   Active  <root><Loan>1001</Loan><Atty>False</Atty></root>
2   Failed  <root><Loan>1021</Loan><Atty>True</Atty></root>
3   Failed  <root><Loan>1004</Loan><Atty>True</Atty></root>
4   Active  <root><Loan>1034</Loan><Atty>True</Atty></root>
```

Here , I want to  get the status ,ID and LOAD where loan number =1004.
How do we can create sql query ?
Load column is XML type .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT
    ID, [Status], [Load]
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHEre
WHERE
    Load.value('(/root/Loan)[1]', 'int') = 1004
```